# Show products that are not included in a specific price list?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following 4 tables:

```
create table Productgroup
(
    productgroup_id char(4) primary key,
    productgroupName varchar(25) not null
)

create table Product
(
    product_id char(4) primary key,
    productName varchar(25) not null,
    product_productgroup_id char(4) 
        constraint product_productgroup_id_foreign 
            foreign key references Productgroup(productgroup_id)
)

create table Pricelist
(
    pricelist_id char(4) primary key,
    pricelistName varchar(25) not null
)

create table Productprice
(
    productprice_id int identity(1000, 1) primary key,
    price int not null,
    discount decimal(10,2),
    product_productprice_id char(4) 
         constraint product_productprice_id_foreign 
             foreign key references Product(product_id),
    pricelist_productprice_id char(4) 
         constraint pricelist_productprice_id_foreign 
             foreign key references Pricelist(pricelist_id)
)
```

Each product has a product-group and can be included in different price lists with different prices.

I have 2 price lists so far, a price list called 'Store' and a price list called 'Friday bar'. I want to make a query that show the products and product groups where the product is not included in the price list 'Friday Bar'.

So far, I have this code:

```
SELECT 
    Productgroup.productgroupName, Product.productName 
FROM 
    Product
JOIN 
    Productgroup ON Product.product_productgroup_id = Productgroup.productgroup_id
JOIN 
    Productprice ON Product.product_id = Productprice.product_productprice_id
JOIN 
    Pricelist ON Productprice.pricelist_productprice_id = Pricelist.pricelist_id
WHERE 
    Pricelist.pricelistName != 'Friday bar'
```

But the problem with this query is that it shows both the products included in the Friday bar and the products not included in the Friday bar. However, the products that are ONLY in the price list 'Friday Bar' are not displayed. But it is supposed to show only those products that are not in the price list 'Friday bar'.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: use `pricelist_productprice_id` instead like this `WHERE pricelist_productprice_id  <> (the price list ID for friday bar)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you join you're can't exclude it when it exists in other price lists because you'll get a row for each. Instead you have to check specifically whether a price in that price list exists e.g.

```
SELECT PG.productgroupName, P.productName
FROM Product P
INNER JOIN Productgroup PG ON P.product_productgroup_id = PG.productgroup_id
where not exists (
  select 1
  from Productprice PP
  inner join Pricelist PL ON PP.pricelist_productprice_id = PL.pricelist_id
  where P.product_id = PP.product_productprice_id
  and PL.pricelistName = 'Friday bar'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `left join`:

```
SELECT Productgroup.productgroupName, Product.productName
    FROM Product JOIN
         Productgroup 
         ON Product.product_productgroup_id = Productgroup.productgroup_id JOIN
         Productprice
         ON Product.product_id = Productprice.product_productprice_id JOIN
         Pricelist
         ON Productprice.pricelist_productprice_id = Pricelist.pricelist_id AND
            Pricelist.pricelistName = 'Friday bar'
WHERE Pricelist.pricelist_id IS NULL;
```